# keep elements in box regardles of amount of text in the first one

Tags: html, css

I have sayings and authors.

if a saying has enough amount of text - everything is ok - first example

if a saying is short - the design is ugly - second example.

how to keep  everything in box and on center - regardles of amount of text in `story` ?

```css
.wrap{
  height:140px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
  padding:0 25px;
  background:gold;
}

.story{
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:justify;
  margin:5px 0;
}

.auth{
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:right;
  margin:5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
<div class='story'>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<div class='auth'>author</div>
</div>

<br>

<div class='wrap'>
<div class='story'>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<div class='auth'>author</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you mean by the center is vertically center or horizontally?

Comment: @AtulRajput everything should be on both center inside `wrap` and `auth` aligned right with `story`

Comment: dude you need to put more thought into this, why do you have `height: 140px` and `display: flex` listed twice? I feel like you haven't tried very hard, but yea `align-items: center` and `justify-content: center` should be fine

Comment: you should research flex-box, it uses a concept of `width: min-content` which will be the longest word in a paragraph, for example

Answer (score 0):

as discussed with you in comment you can do it like this, if needed something else please let me know

```css
.wrap{
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:space-between;
  padding:0 25px;
  background:gold;
margin-bottom: 20px;
flex-direction: column;
}

.story{
  text-align:justify;
  margin:5px 0;
}

.auth{
  margin:5px 0 5px 20px;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
<div class='story'>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<div class='auth'>author</div>
</div>

<br>

<div class='wrap'>
<div class='story'>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<div class='auth'>author</div>
</div>

<div class='wrap'>
<div class='story'>lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<div class='auth'>author</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the author is below story and right-aligned as you asked

Comment: your second example - author is not aligned right with story

Comment: what do you mean by aligned right, its need to be on right side as i understood? where you want that author

Comment: need a box placed on both center of the gold wrap. inside that box are story and auth aligned right

Comment: I dont know what you want, need a box placed on both center of the gold wrap, maybe my English is not that good, can you pls show in question by a image , what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below:

```css
.wrap{
  height:140px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  align-content:center;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  padding:0 25px;
  margin:5px;
  background:gold;
}

.story{
  text-align:justify;
  margin:5px 0;
}

.auth{
  margin:5px 0 5px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
<div class='story'>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<div class='auth'>author</div>
</div>


<div class='wrap'>
<div class='story'>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<div class='auth'>author</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you asking for your .story text to be horizontally centered if it doesn't fill the full space? There are 2 options.

First, the reason you're not seeing the result you want is because the width of your .story div will be 100%, and there's no easy way to adjust that to fit the content of your text. By the flex property, your div IS centered horizontally; however, it takes up the full width, so you don't notice.

One solution would be to set your text-align to center, but that doesn't seem to be the result you want, since you already have it set to justify.

So the solution I suggest is to reset your horizontal margin from 0 to auto. This will fill the horizontal margin based on the available space equally on each side.

Is this what you're asking for?

Also, as @neaumusic already said, you should remove the duplicate CSS entries.

```css
.wrap{
  height:140px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
  padding:0 25px;
  background:gold;
}

.story{
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:justify;
  margin:5px 0;
}

.auth{
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:right;
  margin:5px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
<div class='story'>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<div class='auth'>author</div>
</div>

<br>

<div class='wrap'>
<div class='story'>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<div class='auth'>author</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps instead of downrating my explanation and answer, you need to clarify what you're asking for. Based on all the other commentary around your question, no one else knows what you want to accomplish, either. Best of luck.